# Search Schema Configuration Disabled SP Online

Tags: search, sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint online instance that I want to edit the Search Schema.  From SPOnline Central Admin I select "Manage Search Schema" in the Search section and search for a Managed Property to edit. When I click on the property to edit it all options are grayed out and unavailable.   THis does not happen with my on-prem instance so I am not sure what else needs to be configured for it to be enabled.

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure you can not create or modify managed properties in Office 365

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also create new Managed Properties for Text and Yes/No types. If you need additional Managed Properties you have to map crawled properties to the built in Managed Properties Date00, Date01, Decimal00 etc. If you need Refinable properties Microsoft supplies you with RefinableString00, RefinableDate00 etc. Usually there are 10 or more available, but for performance reasons, you cannot create them yourself.

If you check your on-premises version you will see all of these as well.

Answer (score 3):

They are almost un-editable. But there are two things you can do editing a managed property:

- **Advanced Searchable Settings**: Enables viewing and changing the full-text index and weight of the managed property.
- Add **Mappings to crawled properties** and the list shows all the crawled properties that are mapped to this managed property. A managed property can get its content from one or more crawled properties.

But that's it today. Chances are that more options will be added in the future, since development focus are high on SharePoint Online at the moment.